# GitHub Codespace secrets when using VSCode devcontainers locally

Tags: environment-variables, vscode-devcontainer, github-codespaces

I am using a GCP service account file as a GitHub Codespaces secret, and I am able to access it from the Codespace container, [as explained here](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-your-codespaces/managing-encrypted-secrets-for-your-codespaces).

Now, I want to also support developing locally without GitHub Codespaces but still use VSCode devcontainers.

I also hold the service account file on my local filesystem, but outside of the git repo (for obvious reasons). How should I reference it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mounts` property in `devcontainer.json`. Codespaces ignores `bind` mounts (more info can be found in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference#_image-or-dockerfile-specific-properties)) so you should be able to mount the file from your local filesystem without affecting how your Codespaces are built/ run.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

I have release an extension on the marketplace to solve this usecase: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pomdtr.secrets

It stores the secrets in the user keychain. Since it is a web extension, it runs on the client and also works with devcontainers.

#### Previous Answer

You can use the `terminal.integrated.env.linux` to pass the secret in your `settings.json` file.

You can disable settings sync using the `settingsSync.ignoredSettings` array:

```json
{
  "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "GITHUB_TOKEN": "<your-token>"
  },
  "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux"
  ]
}
```